# Interpreting Spearman's correlation in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation, p-value, interpretation

Here are two ranked variables, their corresponding correlation test, followed by my understanding of the results:

```
x1 = c(32, 16, 22,  8, 18,  1,  9, 10,  7,  2, 21, 26, 15, 17,  5, 12, 
       19, 25, 13, 20, 29, 24,  6,  4, 14, 23, 31, 27, 11, 28,  3, 30)
y1 = c( 8,  4,  6,  5, 14, 11, 18, 13, 10, 16, 28,  2, 24, 26, 32, 27, 
       15, 21, 29,  9, 17, 23,  3, 30, 25, 31,  7, 20,  1, 19, 22, 12)
cor.test(x1, y1, method = "spearman", exact = F)
#   Spearman's rank correlation rho
# 
# data:  x1 and y1
# S = 6052, p-value = 0.5517
# alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
# sample estimates:
#        rho 
# -0.1092375
```

My understanding is that there is a very weak negative correlation but the null hypothesis of "There is no monotonic correlation between the variables" can not be rejected as `p-value>0.05`.

```
x2 = c(30,  8, 20, 31, 24,  1, 15, 17,  6, 23, 25, 19,  3,  7, 32, 12, 
       16,  4, 28, 13, 18, 27,  9, 22,  5, 29, 21, 10, 26, 14,  2, 11)
y2 = c(19,  4, 14, 32, 22,  5, 10, 31,  6, 30, 29, 25, 21, 27, 20,  3, 
       24,  7, 26, 15,  1, 23, 11, 17,  9, 12, 18,  8, 28,  2, 13, 16)
cor.test(x2, y2, method = "spearman", exact = F)
#   Spearman's rank correlation rho
# 
# data:  x2 and y2
# S = 2492, p-value = 0.001313
# alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
# sample estimates:
#       rho 
# 0.5432551
```

From my understanding this represents a moderate positive correlation and I I can reject the null hypothesis that "There is no monotonic correlation between the variables" as `p-value<0.05`.

However, my confusion arises from the statement `alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0` in both the tests. Due to my confusion, I revised my concepts from [here](http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/spearmans.pdf), and my initial understanding seems to be fine.

My question is, why does R say `alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0` in both the cases? How should I interpret the results in either case?

Comment: R is merely stating the alternative hypothesis (that the "true rho" - i.e. the population correlation - is nonzero). It's not telling you whether you rejected the null or not. That alternative hypothesis is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretations seem fine to me.

In both cases, `R` is testing your observed rank correlation against a possible true rank correlation of 0.  That is, it is checking if it's reasonable to imagine that your data are a sample from a population in which the two variables' ranks are unrelated.  The null hypothesis was the same for both tests.  Whether or not the results are significant doesn't change the nature of the null against which the data were tested.

Also, when it says "alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0", that is telling you that it performed a two-tailed test of the null.  If it said, "alternative hypothesis: true rho is greater than 0", or "alternative hypothesis: true rho is less than 0", that would mean that `R` performed a one-tailed test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However, I am still unclear on one point. Isn't the decision whether "it's reasonable to imagine that your data are a sample from a population in which the two variables' ranks are unrelated" based on `p-values`?

Comment: Sort of, @DotPi. The p-value is the probability of getting a result as extreme or more extreme than your result, if the null hypothesis were true. At a certain point, people no longer think it's reasonable to imagine the data are from such a population, & set that level as alpha, the type I error rate they are willing to live with.